# fix a popup box and make the background scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this pop box, which get triggered when i click on a image, now i have 8 images on which i have applied the popup box, i want to make the popup box fixed and the background scrolling so that, regardless to the image position, the pop up box will remain same position on the screen.

```js
(function(){

    var container = document.documentElement,
        popup = document.querySelector( '.avgrund-popup' ),
        cover = document.querySelector( '.avgrund-cover' ),
        currentState = null;

    addClass( container, 'avgrund-ready' );

    // Deactivate on ESC
    function onDocumentKeyUp( event ) {
        if( event.keyCode === 27 ) {
            deactivate();
        }
    }

    // Deactivate on click outside
    function onDocumentClick( event ) {
        if( event.target === cover ) {
            deactivate();
        }
    }

    function activate( state ) {
        document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentClick, false );

        removeClass( popup, currentState );
        addClass( popup, 'no-transition' );
        addClass( popup, state );

        setTimeout( function() {
            removeClass( popup, 'no-transition' );
            addClass( container, 'avgrund-active' );
        }, 0 );

        currentState = state;
    }

    function deactivate() {
        document.removeEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'click', onDocumentClick, false );

        removeClass( container, 'avgrund-active' );
    }

    function disableBlur() {
        addClass( document.documentElement, 'no-blur' );
    }

    function addClass( element, name ) {
        element.className = element.className.replace( /\s+$/gi, '' ) + ' ' + name;
    }

    function removeClass( element, name ) {
        element.className = element.className.replace( name, '' );
    }

    window.avgrund = {
        activate: activate,
        deactivate: deactivate,
        disableBlur: disableBlur
    }

})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup_container{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p{
 margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.32;
}

.pop_img{
 cursor:pointer;
}

button {
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
 border: 0px;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
 border-radius:50%;

 cursor: pointer;
 color:#91cd85;
 font-size:20px;

 -webkit-transition: 0.15s background ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.15s background ease;
     -ms-transition: 0.15s background ease;
      -o-transition: 0.15s background ease;
         transition: 0.15s background ease;
}

button:hover{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#91cd85;
}
 button+button {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

.popup_container{
 background: #fff;
 font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #222;
}
 .avgrund-active body {
  -webkit-transform: scale( 0.9 );
     -moz-transform: scale( 0.9 );
      -ms-transform: scale( 0.9 );
       -o-transform: scale( 0.9 );
          transform: scale( 0.9 );
 }

 .avgrund-active .avgrund-cover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 }

.avgrund-contents {
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
 max-width: 400px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
}
 .avgrund-active .avgrund-contents {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
     -moz-filter: blur(2px);
      -ms-filter: blur(2px);
       -o-filter: blur(2px);
          filter: blur(2px);
 }
 .no-blur.avgrund-active .avgrund-contents {
  -webkit-filter: none;
     -moz-filter: none;
      -ms-filter: none;
       -o-filter: none;
          filter: none;
 }

.avgrund-popup {
 display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6 );
 border-radius: 3px;

 -webkit-transform: scale( 0.8 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 0.8 );
     -ms-transform: scale( 0.8 );
      -o-transform: scale( 0.8 );
         transform: scale( 0.8 );
}

.pop_head{
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.inner_content{
  width:100%;
  max-height:250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

 .pop_head h2{
  max-height:350px; 
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inner_content .details{
  margin-top:30px;
  line-height:15px;
 
}

 .avgrund-active .avgrund-popup {
    display:block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale( 1.1 );
     -moz-transform: scale( 1.1 );
      -ms-transform: scale( 1.1 );
       -o-transform: scale( 1.1 );
          transform: scale( 1.1 );
 }
 .avgrund-popup.stack {
  -webkit-transform: scale( 1.5 );
     -moz-transform: scale( 1.5 );
      -ms-transform: scale( 1.5 );
       -o-transform: scale( 1.5 );
          transform: scale( 1.5 );
 }
 .avgrund-active .avgrund-popup.stack {
  -webkit-transform: scale( 1.1 );
     -moz-transform: scale( 1.1 );
      -ms-transform: scale( 1.1 );
       -o-transform: scale( 1.1 );
          transform: scale( 1.1 );
 }


.avgrund-ready body,
.avgrund-ready .avgrund-contents,
.avgrund-ready .avgrund-popup,
.avgrund-ready .avgrund-cover {
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
         transform-origin: 50% 50%;

 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
     -ms-transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
      -o-transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
         transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
}
.avgrund-ready .avgrund-popup.no-transition {
 -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
     -ms-transition: none;
      -o-transition: none;
         transition: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup_container">
<div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>
  
  <div class="avgrund-contents">
 <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png" /></a>
</div>

  
  
<div class="avgrund-popup">
 <div class=pop_head>
  <button onclick="avgrund.deactivate();">x</button>
    <h2>Title</h2>
   </div>
 <div class=inner_content>
  <p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>

<p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>    
    
<p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p> 
    
<p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>  
    
<p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p> 
    
<p class=details>You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>     
 </div>
  </div>
```

this is what i am trying to acheive
https://codepen.io/digstheone/pen/xVNrzJ

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly your problem is, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Background is already scrolling. Could you again elaborate the question ?

Comment: yes the background is scrolling but the popbox should not, just like:
https://codepen.io/digstheone/pen/xVNrzJ

Comment: i want the content to remain static or fixed and the background scrolling, so that, popbox position will not matter, even if my i am opening the last image

Answer (score 0):

I'll generate the popup outside the container of the images and then play with the z-index, so that the the images stack on the underground.

Answer (score 0):

Put your modal at the top like following html and use follwoing css as well.

```
<div class="popup_container">
  <div class="avgrund-popup  stack  stack">
 <div class="pop_head">
  <button onclick="avgrund.deactivate();">x</button>
    <h2>Title</h2>
   </div>
    <div class="inner_content">
        <p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>

<p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>    

<p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p> 

<p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>  

<p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p> 

<p class="details">You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
</p>     
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>

  <div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>

  <div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>

  <div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>

  <div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>

  <div class="avgrund-contents">
    <a class="pop_img" onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IMPRESSIONS/medical/png/256/doctor.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And Use this css :

```
.avgrund-popup {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.avgrund-popup.stack {
    margin: auto !important;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```